# Mandelbrot set Proof for Bounding Circle of Period 2 Bulb

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, fractals, complex-dynamics

I've been searching and I can't find a proof for the bounding circle of the Period 2 Bulb in a Mandelbrot set.
Its referenced quite a bit that it is a circle with radius of $\frac{1}{4}$ and a centre at '$c = - 1$' but so far I have yet to find anything beyond 'this isn't too hard to prove'.

So any help on even just a link to a proof for that bounding circle would be great.

tldr: Could anyone find or show the proof that the Mandelbrot set period 2 bulb has a bounding circle of radius $\frac{1}{4}$ and centre at '$c = - 1$'

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The period $2$ bulb is the set of $c$ such that $f_c(z) = z^2 + c$ has a cycle of least period $2$ which is not repelling (the derivative of the cycle has magnitude 1 or less), which means that
$$(z_0^2 + c)^2 + c = z_0$$
and
$$| 4 z_0 (z_0^2 + c) | \le 1.$$

In Maxima (a computer algebra system) you can enter

```
solve([(z^2+c)^2 + c = z, 4 * z * (z^2 + c) = D], [z, c]);
```

where $D$ will represent the unit disk (corresponding to the inequality).  Maxima gives four solutions:

$$\left[ \left[ z=-\frac{\sqrt{1-D}+1}{2}\operatorname{,}c=\frac{D-4}{4}\right] \operatorname{,}\left[ z=\frac{\sqrt{1-D}-1}{2}\operatorname{,}c=\frac{D-4}{4}\right] \operatorname{,}\left[ z=-\frac{\sqrt{D}}{2}\operatorname{,}c=-\frac{D+2 \sqrt{D}}{4}\right] \operatorname{,}\left[ z=\frac{\sqrt{D}}{2}\operatorname{,}c=\frac{2 \sqrt{D}-D}{4}\right] \right] $$

The first two solutions have the same $c$, with the two $z$ at different phases of the cycle.  The last two solutions are spurious, with $z = z^2 + c$ (i.e. they are fixed points, not part of a cycle with least period $2$).

Thus the period $2$ bulb, $c = \frac{D - 4}{4}$ (with $D$ the unit disk) is a disk of radius $r = \frac{1}{4}$ centered on $c = -1$.

To be pedantic, one also needs to show that the period $2$ cycle is reachable by iteration starting from $z = 0$, which is achieved by Fatou theorem: every attracting cycle for a polynomial or rational function attracts at least one critical point; $z^2+c$ has only one critical point ($z = 0$) which guarantees that the cycle is reachable (at least within the interior of the bulb).